# Can I bring my own Quran inside the mosque and read?

Tags: quran, masjid

All mosques have the arabic AL Quran in them to read but those like me who do not know arabic can bring my own Quran inside the mosque to read in my language is it allowed.

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. (But going forward, try to learn Arabic because you lose out on great reward by not reading/reciting the Qur'an in its original language).

Comment: My local mosque has qu'rans in several languages; so I don't see it as a problem. I am not sure why you would think it is.

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is Mustahab (recommended) to read the Quran in Arabic because it is the language in which it was sent down. When it is in other languages sometimes the full meaning is lost.

If you can than try to learn Arabic. But it is not haram to read it in other languages because understanding the Quran is also very important.

The reward is higher for

1. Reading, Understanding, Teaching and Implementing the Quran than
2. Reading, Understanding  and Implementing the Quran than
3. Reading and Understanding the Quran than
4. Reading and Teaching the Quran than
5. Reading  the Quran than
6. Listening to the Quran

Nowadays, I have also seen many Muslims *using Quran softwares on their mobile phones* in the masjids to get the language and tafsir that they can understand.